# How to speed up math operations in Python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am writing a code in Python in which I am doing a lot of matrix multiplications on huge matrices. For the performance as well as the speed I am using numpy.einsum. Anyways, that einum is optimized very well, my code works very slowly. This is a reason that I'm looking for a solution to speed it up. I thought that PyCuda might have been helpful, but after doing some research on the Internet, I figured out that I was mistaken. 
Do you have any tips how to improve performance of math operations Python?

For example I have a bunch of this kind of following multiplications:

```
NewMatrix_krls = np.einsum('kK,krls->Krls', C, Matrx_krls)
```

where C is a matrix 1000 by 1000 and a Matrx_krls is 1000 by 1000 by 1000 by 1000.

Comment: There is little we can do to help with so little information.

Comment: I updated it. I'm still not sure if you understand what is my problem.

Comment: Somehow I doubt Numpy is the bottleneck here.  You should profile your code to really determine where it is.

Comment: If you really have excessive calculations going on, you should look into parallel computing. But if it is just a matter of the code completing in 5min instead of 30min, then I would recommend you to just deal with the computation time. See [this](https://xkcd.com/1205/) relevant comic on time optimization.

Comment: That's enormous amount of math. Which platform is faster so that you want to speed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`einsum` constructs an iterator (`ndinter`) that loops (in C) over the problem space.  With the dimensions and indexes in your expression that space is `1000**5` (5 variables, each of size 1000).  That's `10**15` operations.

If the problem involved multiplying 3 or 4 arrays, you might speed things up by splitting it into a couple of `einsum` calls (or a mix of `einsum` and `dot`).  But there's not enough information in your description to suggest that kind of partitioning.

Actually you might be able to cast this in a form that uses `np.dot`.  `Matrx_krls` can be reshaped to a 2d array, combining the `rls` dimensions into one `1000**3` in size.

E.g.  (not tested)

```
np.dot(C.T, Matrx_krls.reshape(1000,-1))
```

For a product of 2 2d arrays, `np.dot` is faster than `einsum`.

(Note I changed your tags to include `numpy` - that will bring it to the attention of more knowledgeable posters).

Answer (score 0):

> 'Matrx_krls is 1000 by 1000 by 1000 by 1000'

So thats a 4-terabyte array, assuming 4-byte floats... I think you are better off investing time in Hadoop than in GPGPU. Even if you stream that data to a GPU, you will see little benefit because of limited PCIE bandwidth.

That, or perhaps explaining why you think you need this kind of operation might help on a higher level.